# how to split up a numeric column in r into 3 separate columns conditional on the value of another variable, with aim of reducing the final dimension

Tags: r, sas, transpose, dcast

I have a very basic R question but I am having a hard time trying to get the right answer. I am trying to translate SAS code to R.

Below is a snap shot of a subset of some data I am working with.
What I wish to do is split up the column market_test into three separate columns based on the Timeperiod_num column.

[image]

This is easily done in SAS by using proc transpose and some of the other variables in the data:

```
proc transpose
data = LA_5_C out = LA_5_E prefix=market_test_;
by business_reg_number entity_name;
var market_test;
id Timeperiod;
quit;
```

which produces the desired output with 3 separate columns for the market test variable.
[image]

I have tried using the function dcast() in R to do this as I have used it to transpose data previously. However, in this case, when I try to execute the code:

```
A_5_E <- (dcast(as.data.table(LA_5_C), business_reg_number + entity_name ~ TimePeriod, value.var = "market_test"))
```

I get the warning "Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'" and whilst the format produces three separate columns the output is not correct, see image below

[image]

I assume this is because the combination of variables I supplied does not uniquely identify one row in the original data set, which suggests the use of an aggregating function but I really don't understand which one I can supply to give me my desired output.

I have also tried to manually split up the market_test column into 3 based on year but this just returns a dataset with the same length as the original when I want it to be of reduced length(number of observations) since the 3 years of market tests will be displayed in the same row for each unique entity.

[image]

I'm really stuck and have been trying multiple different things but I'm not getting anywhere.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

################# EDIT ################

So here is some sample data that is reproducible:

```
bus_reg_no <- c('G01', 'G01', 'G01', 'G02', 'G02', 'G02', 'G03', 'G03' , 'G03')
entity_name <- c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C')
TimePeriod <- c('2020', '2019', '2018', '2020', '2019', '2018', '2020', '2019', '2018')
market_test <- c(NA, 0.9330331232, 0.9969181046, 0.9429920482, 0.9689617356, 0.9764825438, NA, 0.2302289569, 0.7762837775)

dat <- cbind(bus_reg_no, entity_name, TimePeriod, market_test)
```

I want to split the column market_test up into 3 separate columns for each year in the data for each entity. So my desired output will have a reduced length, and for each row for each entitity there will be a separate column showing the market test figure for the years 2020, 2019, 2018 separately.
So surely a code to execute what I want will use at least the variables entity_name, TimePeriod and market_test

Comment: Please include data using the output of `dput(your_data)` and include the code you have tried so as to make a [MRE]

Comment: Anyway, it looks like a typo in your `dcast`: Try: `dcast(as.data.table(LA_5_C), business_reg_number + entity_name ~ Timeperiod_num, value.var = "market_test")`

Comment: I still get the warning "Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'"